# Iphone NSDateFormatter - image files could not be loaded

Tags: ios, time, timezone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

In my sqlite db I have a NSDate field and I create a image file with a unique name using this code and based on that date I load the image.

`NSDateFormatter *digitsOnlyDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [digitsOnlyDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];
    NSString *imageDateString = [digitsOnlyDateFormatter stringFromDate:[self imageDate]];`

If I change the time zone from iphone settings and I add a new record in db, other images saved with another time zone could not be loaded.

I think there is a problem with conversion.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of `NSDateFormatter`s format can be overridden by user settings: specifically the choice  of AM/PM versus 24-hour time.

You can solve this by setting the formatter's locale. (Note: this is something you should only do in situations like this to create strings that need to be consistent across locales and won't be displayed to the user).

```
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[digitsOnlyFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
```

P.S. if you want the string to be made relative to the same timezone as well, you should also set the formatter's timezone:

```
[digitsOnlyFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
```

Comment: But what happens with the already saved image files with whatever time zone format? That string could not be matched with GMT. This fix I want to develop.

Comment: If you're saying you want to open old saved image files that were saved with some random locale and time zone, then you'll need to set the same locale and timezone in order to generate the right string.

The point of my answer is that you should set the timezone and locale consistently each time, so that `[digitsOnlyFormatter stringFromDate:someDate]` will always give the same output for a given date.